# Why is "ing" used in the following sentence?

Tags: verbs, gerunds

" meaning basically can they prevent the other team from scor**ing** "

Yet I'm sure this is not progressive present. So why do we put "ing" after "scor" ?

Comment: "Scoring" isn't being used to form the present progressive tense. It's being used as a gerund, the indirect object of the verb "prevent." By the way, you need to put "the" before "other team."

Comment: @Newgate. You are right. It is not the present progressive (which, by the way, is an aspect not a tense). It has the semantic category of aspectuality, but not the syntactic category of aspect which requires a form of "be". The last comment is wrong, in that "scoring" is not an indirect object, but a gerund-participial clause functioning as complement of "from".

Comment: @BillJ And if the 'from' is dropped?

Comment: Then the subordinate clause would be "the other team scoring" functioning as complement of "prevent". But still no indirect object.

Answer (score 1):

One interpretation (that "scoring" is a clause) is given in another answer. Another interpretation is that "scoring" is a gerund functioning as the object (or complement) of the preposition "from". (This is a rather common function for gerunds.) "Scoring" is the gerund form of the verb "to score".

Answer (score 0):

As BillJ commented:

> You are right. It is not the present progressive (which, by the way, is an aspect not a tense). It has the semantic category of aspectuality, but not the syntactic category of aspect which requires a form of "be". The last comment is wrong, in that "scoring" is not an indirect object, but a gerund-participial clause functioning as complement of "from".